# Construct expression for where through lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-4

**The situation**

I have a method that takes in a POCO. This POCO is like the following

```
    private class SearchCriteria
    {
      public string name get;set;
      public string age get;set;
      public string talent get;set;
    .. 
.... 
     }
```

The method basically has a query to the db , that uses the above criteria.

```
public void query(SearchCriteria crit)
{
  if(crit.name!=null && crit.age!=null && crit.talent !=null)
   {
     dbContext.Students.Where(c=>c.name ==crit.name &&    c.age==crit.age...)
   }
  else if(crit.name !=null && crit.age!=null)
  {
  }
  else if(....
  {
  }
```

As you can see there is a definite problem above , where in, in case of large number of criteria, I will have to write a lot of if-elses to drop out specific arguments from the where clause .

**The possible solution ?**

I am actually new to the lambda expressions world but I believe we must be having a facility which would allow us to do something like below.

`dbContext.Students.Where(processCriteria(searchCriteriaPOCO))`.

Can you folks lead me to the proper direction ?. Thanks

Comment: If any of the answers sufficiently addressed your question, would you be so kind as to select it as the answer, or alternatively if you found a better way yourself, please post that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a queryable and then keep adding where clauses to it. That way you only need to test each possible criteria the once and also only generate the number of where clauses that are absolutely needed.

```
IQueryable<Student> q = dbContext.Students.AsQueryable();

if (crit.name != null)
    q = q.Where(c => c.name == crit.name);

if (crit.age != null)
    q = q.Where(c => c.age== crit.age);
```

Comment: Nit: I'd either use `var`, or drop the `.AsQueryable()`. The latter has no value if you specify the type explicitly.

Comment: Your right. I was doing it from the top of my head.

Comment: Phil , if successive IFs get executed , wouldn't it replace the value in "q" ? . Such that only the last where clause is in "q". Or will all of the successful ifs accumulate their respective where clauses?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib the `q.Where(...)` returns a new `IQueryable<Student>` instance that includes the where clause expression. You can chain where expressions.

Comment: Alex so that would mean that if both the ifs are true in the above code snippet , we would have two queries with the database right ? .So if we have ten ifs , will be be going to and fro with the DB server , ten times ?

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying that this answer uses the same basic idea as @PhilWright's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29598800/2573395). It just wraps it up in an extension method that applies this pattern for you, and allows you to have a syntax that reads nice.

```
public static class SearchExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Student> Query(this SearchCriteria criteria, IQueryable<Student> studentQuery)
    {
        return studentQuery
            .Match(criteria.name, (student) => student.name == criteria.name)
            .Match(criteria.age, (student) => student.age == criteria.age)
            .Match(criteria.talent, (student) => student.talent == criteria.talent);
            // add expressions for other fields if needed.
    }

    private static IQueryable<Student> Match<T>(
        this IQueryable<Student> studentQuery,
        T criterionValue,
        Expression<Func<Student, bool>> whereClause) where T : class
    {
        // only use the expression if the criterion value is non-null.
        return criterionValue == null ? studentQuery : studentQuery.Where(whereClause);
    }
}
```

You can then use it in your code like this:

```
var criteria = new SearchCriteria() { 
    name = "Alex", 
    talent = "Nosepicking" 
};
var results = criteria.Query(dbContext.Students);
```

Comment: Thats really genius and neat.

Comment: and I really envy your talent :D .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, as the code example is not the clearest I've seen, but for your specific example, I would think the following should be fine:

```
dbContext.Students.Where(c => (crit.name == null || crit.name == c.name) &&
    (crit.age == null || crit.age == c.age) &&
    (crit.talent == null || crit.talent == c.talent));
```

No need to chain a bunch of `if` statements.

For more complicated scenarios, you might prefer something like [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like this:

```
dbContext.Students.Where(c=>(crit.name == null || c.name ==crit.name) && ...)
```

A search criterion which is null will give a subexpression which is  always true.